# OOP School work (beginner)

Tags: java

As is, it does compile.

Bug = printing breed and declawed statements on same line. Cannot get rid of this bug for some reason

Bug = unable to get the result logic to compile and print for 
console (newb)

There are examples a little like mine posted but they really haven't done anything to help because they are not exactly what I think I'm supposed to be going for. One worked perfect but uses and array and we aren't even to that part yet in my course. Here are the teachers instructions and some tips he gave me and then my code so far. Some of it is commented out since I'm trying to get rid of bugs before printing the result. Also I did change some of the names for convenience until the assignment is complete. Sorry for any formatting issues. Any advice?

In this order:

1. assignment instruction for class file
2. tip from the teacher
3. class file code so far
4. assignment for the driver file
5. driver file code so far

   1. ASSIGNMENT INSTRUCTIONS FOR THE CLASS FILE:

Create a new class called Cat that includes the functionality below

The new class has the attributes of:
    name – type String
    age – type integer
    weight – type double
    breed - type String
    declawed - type boolean - true for has no claws, false for has claws

Be sure your classes have a reasonable complement of constructor, accessor and mutator methods. Every member variable must have at least one independent accessor and one independent mutator.

Example:
    public void setName(String name) mutator used to set name
    public void setBreed(String breed) mutator used to set the breed
    public void set(Boolean declawed) used to set claws or not
****(You must overload the set method to set deClawed value)**  what is this?**
    public String getName() accessor used to get name
    public String getBreed() accessor used to get breed
    public boolean getBoolean() access used to get the value of declawed

Ensure you use the “this” reference from within this class when referring to every instance variable or instance method of the current object.

2. TIP FROM THE TEACHER:
   for your IF statement you will only use Age and Claw methods but
   then at the end when you print out everything you will need the rest of the
   methods. You can create a display method to display all the print
   statements for each category such as name, age, etc...then it becomes
   easier to display this in the main method - here would be your code in the
   main method:

   System.out.println("The cat data entered is: \n");
    myCat1.display();
    myCat2.display();
    myCat3.display();
3. code for class file so far

/*************************************************************************************************
*Cat.java
*Jonathan Nees
*
*Cha. 6 OOP
*************************************************************************************************/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cat
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double weight;
    private String breed;
    private boolean declawed;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
    return this.name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
    this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
    return this.age;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight)
    {
    this.weight = weight;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
    return this.weight;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed)
    {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getBreed()
    {
    return this.breed;
    }

    public void setDeclawed(boolean declawed)
    {
    this.declawed = declawed;
    }

    public boolean isDeclawed()
    {
    if (!this.declawed == false)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void display()
    {
    System.out.print("Enter the name of Cat: ");
    this.name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter the age of Cat: ");
    this.age = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the weight of Cat: ");
    this.weight = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the breed of Cat: ");
    this.breed = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Does the cat have claws? True or False?: ");
    this.declawed = input.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

4. Assignment instructions for the driver file

Write a driver program that reads in 3 pets of type Cat and prints out the name and age of all cats with claws and over 3 years old.

The following information should be read in:
        Name (as String)
        Age (as int)
        Weight (as double)
        Breed (as String)
        DeClawed  (as boolean)

Ensure you use the accessor methods to check the age and claws.

5. code for driver file so far

/*************************************************************************************************
*CatDriver.java
*Jonathan Nees
*
*Cha. 6 OOP Driver
*************************************************************************************************/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CatDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cat Cat1 = new Cat();
    Cat Cat2 = new Cat();
    Cat Cat3 = new Cat();

    Cat1.display();
    System.out.println();
    Cat2.display();
    System.out.println();
    Cat3.display();
    System.out.println();

    //*for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    //{
    //  System.out.println("The cats over 3 with claws are:");
    //  if ((!this.age() <= 3) && (this.Declawed() == true))
    //  {
    //      System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
    //      System.out.println("Age: " + this.age + "Years Old");
        //  }
    //}
    }
}
```

Like I said I've commented some out to work out the bugs before doing the result.

It almost works! Sorta...

Comment: please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Read it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: If no one wants to help me fine but I'm not just going to submit someone else work because it works. I'll take my little half credit for making it compile before I steal someone else's code. I want help and tips for making mine operate. I read it though.

Comment: Instead of checking if `this.declawed` is true or not just return the value. `public boolean isDeclawed()
    { return this.declawed; }`

Comment: Thanks @stacksonstacks. You're right. I have to check it again in the main anyway. Got anything else?

Comment: You have created setter methods but you aren't using them you're assigning to variables directly. e.g. `this.name = input.nextLine();` should become `this.setName(input.nextLine());` Secondly you should use `System.out.println` to print per line.

Comment: @stacksonstacks Have you compiled it? I tried this before but changed it back since I keep getting a cannot find symbol error on all five variables. with the error uptick on this dot (this.)

Comment: @stacksonstacks  the System.out.println I just compiled force the input to be entered on the next line. I need it on the same line. Still giving a hard time with printing breed and declawed on the same line and not accepting input for breed too. never seen that happen until this assignment. it has me puzzled.

Comment: You're on the right track with your code, keep at it. I can't help you much more without doing your homework for you. Next time you post a question be specific and concise with the problem description. It helps people help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also welcome to StackOverflow!!

Comment: can't figure it out huh? Just kiddin' I understand. I can't!  You do  realize though that you didn't help at all though and that everything I brought up is in the body of my message right? I was very specific. Thanks again though for tryin though @stacksonstacks. I appreciate the welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work.  I rewrote your display method using setter methods and it did the trick.  Also, your declawed setter method is written a little confusingly so you may want to tinker with it.
Try this:

```
public void display()
{
    System.out.print("Enter the name of Cat: ");
    this.setName(input.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Enter the age of Cat: ");
    this.setAge(Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine()));
    System.out.print("Enter the weight of Cat: ");
    this.setWeight(Double.valueOf(input.nextLine()));
    System.out.print("Enter the breed of Cat: ");
    this.setBreed(input.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Does the cat have claws? True or False?: ");
    this.setDeclawed(!Boolean.valueOf(input.nextLine()));
}
```

Comment: We haven't gone over .valueOf so i'll have to check that out. Thanks @MatthewGasiewski  It did work but I've never had it print on the same line that way before. In case it happens again it would be nice to know why it was bugging. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not positive why it was bugging out. It happened to me as well. Java seems to like casting the string input better than the way you were handling it.
By the way, I'm not sure that your commented out 'for' loop is going to work for you.  You probably want to load the objects into an array in order to cycle through a loop like that.

Comment: also, looking back on my code, you can probably just pass in the value of the input.nextDouble, or input.nextInt methods instead of casting the strings.

Comment: actually I'm pretty sure that method of syntax is what fixed the same line bug. I tried it both ways and this was the only way it worked.